# Unity3d ARTookit5 Blurred camera on android mobile

Tags: android, mobile, unity-game-engine, artoolkit

i'm trying to do a simple AR scene with NFT image that i've created with genTextData. The result works fairly well in unity editor, but once compiled and run on an android device, the camera resolution is very bad and there's no focus at all.

My marker is rather small (3 cm picture), and the camera is so blurred that the AR cannot identify the marker from far away. I have to put the phone right in front of it (still verrrrryy blurred) and it will show my object but with a lot of flickering and jittering.

I tried playing with the filter fields (Sample rate/cutoff..), it helped just a little bit wit the flickering of the object, but it would never display it from far away..i always have to put my phone like right in front of it. The result that i want should be: detecting the small marker (sharp resolution or/and good focus) from a fair distance away from it..just like the distance from your computer screen to your eyes.

The problem could be camera resolution and focus, or it could be something else. But i'm pretty sure that the AR cannot identify the marker points because of the blurriness.

Any ideas or solutions about this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here:
http://augmentmy.world/augmented-reality-unity-games-artoolkit-video-resolution-autofocus

I compiled the Unity plugin java part and set it to use the highest resolution from your phone. Also the auto focus mode is activated.

Tell me if that helps.